# If excel finds a match, then move to next blank space

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

Hello all:
I have an excel sheet like

```
ID      Name
12      Paul
12      Robert
15      John
12      George
```

I need to change it to look like

```
ID     Name
12     Paul     Robert     George
15     John
```

Haven't been able to find how to solve it. Many thanks

Comment: Can you try to format your question, so that it is possible to see to which Row/Column your data belongs before and after?

Answer (score 0):

This sub starts writing data to cells and looks for matching data.  If it finds a match, it writes the name on the same row.  If it doesn't find a match, it writes it to the next cell in the output column

```
Sub RewriteTable()

    Dim vaInput As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rOutput As Range

    Set rOutput = Sheet1.Range("D1") 'define where to start output

    vaInput = Sheet1.Range("A1:B5") 'change to suit your date

    'write the header
    rOutput.Value = vaInput(1, 1)
    rOutput.Offset(0, 1).Value = vaInput(1, 2)

    For i = 2 To UBound(vaInput, 1)
        'find the ID in the output column
        Set rFound = rOutput.EntireColumn.Find(vaInput(i, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole)

        'if ID not found
        If rFound Is Nothing Then

            'write to next empty cell in output column
            With Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, rOutput.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Value = vaInput(i, 1)
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = vaInput(i, 2)
            End With
        Else

            'write to next empty cell in found row
            Sheet1.Cells(rFound.Row, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = vaInput(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```